# Flow and capturing Display Text on screen

Tags: visual-workflow, leads, fields, object

I am attempting to build a guided actions list using flow on the leads object.

What I've completed so far is:

1. Assigning RecordID
2. Getting Lead fields
3. Screen that displays 3 questions (Display Text) & 3 text boxes for their answers.

What I would like to do, is to capture the answers from #3 textboxes, but I am not quite sure how to do this?

Comment: See the [Flow Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder?trail_id=build-flows-with-flow-builder) trailhead for creating variables, screens, and how they connect with one another

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the flow's current setup, it's hard to tell precisely where you might be stuck, but generally speaking, you simply need to use an Assignment to assign the values from the text boxes to the record, then use a Fast Update to save the changes back to the database.